# hide or remove uiLabels for performance

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, release, uilabel, hidden

I have 200+ uiLabels on a long scrollview, I need to improve scrolling performance. Is it better to hide and unhide labels, or release them and recreate them, when they are out of view?
I have put tags on them, I am currently using those to hide / unhide with:

```
for (int i=0; i<42; i++) {
        [theScroller viewWithTag:i].hidden = NO;
    }
```

and visa versa, triggered by scroll contentOffset.y values..

I have my uiLabels collection in a plist so its also easy to release and rebuild them?

thanks for any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mark yes it would be better to release the labels,as if they are out of view,not in use,so they will improve the performance and also help you for memory management.

Comment: to release a uiLabel will I call: for (int i=0; i<42; i++) {         [release [theScroller viewWithTag:i]];     } ? and will that make the label disapear?

Comment: @mark remove this way with in the loop write  [[theScroller viewWithTag:i] release];, not like this  [release [theScroller viewWithTag:i]];.The above mentioned by me will release the labels.

Comment: thanks Sabby, just one other thing! I have seen that when I add tags to my objects as I make them, I should not use 0 or 1, have you (or anyone) heard of this?

Comment: No mark I haven't heard that,even i use the tag from 0 for my custom image picker as well.You can do that i think so.You can google for that.Best of Luck bro........If my above answer helped you then please accept it as well.

Comment: I had to use: [[theScroller viewWithTag:i] removeFromSuperview]; in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Having 200+ views reduces performances due to:

- Memory usage
- Display management / animations

It would absolutely be better to remove and release hidden labels and recreate them when needed: memory footprint would be lower and the superview would have only a few subviews to manage (plus the overhead of recreating labels is not so high).

If your scrollview + labels behavior is close to what a table view does, there is room for  further improvement: label reuse. Remove hidden labels from their superview, change their title / style and re-add them at their new position.

Comment: Thanks for the remove / release advice. I don't think I can use a table or reuse labels as all my labels are different sizes?

Comment: It's possible to update the style and frame of your labels on-the-go (though it requires more work on your part to recompute the frame). However you could start with just the remove-release + recreate later and see if it's sufficient for you.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that may help performance is to set your labels as opaque. The performance will decrease when using views with transparent backgrounds.

Creating them on the fly is definitely a solution, however, you may notice that the scrolling may hang every now and then or that the labels will not appear only after a short while after you've scrolled.

Another solution would be to use the approach from [this article](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/). The idea is that you would pre-render the labels on the view and end up with a single static view that should work pretty nicely when you're scrolling around.

Comment: many thanks, I'll have a read of the article, my scrollView is 92000 px long though!!

Comment: With regards the transparent issue I do have a large set of uilabels which I have rotated 90 degs and their background color is set to clear, any workaround?

Comment: hmm reading the article the method deals with the transparent problem anyway! I will read on...

Comment: woah, seems a little tricky on the 1st read through, I need a simple method that snapshots my scrollView with it's hundreds of labels and then treats that as one pre rendered view. Any other articles or links from anyone would be a great help...

Comment: I'm going to try the release/create methods talked about on this page 1st, but I will keep researching this pre-rendered method as it looks like being ideal...

Comment: @Mark You need to need to do it with in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a tableView insteand of scroll view if each label is rigid.

Use a custom table cell and each cell have your label.

Comment: Can I use a tableView when all my labels are different sizes and colors?

Comment: You can config it in real time.